# Undo multiple git merges

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-commit, git-revert

I have two git branches (master and fix_log_messages). I have been making various commits in the fix_log_messages branch and then periodically merging these changes/commits into master. As a result, the master branch contains multiple merges, due to the periodic merging of fix_log_messages branch into master branch.

I now need to remove all the commits which belong to fix_log_messages branch from master branch.  In other words I need to undo multiple merges. I understand that I can revert a single merge using `git revert -m 1 <merge-commit>`.  But what would be the workflow for removing multiple merges on a branch?

FYI - Changes to master have already been pushed to remote.  All merges were performed using `git merge --no-ff fix_log_messages`.

Comment: Are there commits on `master` other than the merge commits, and which you want to preserve? Or are the merges the only additional commits on `master`? The approach would be quite different for the two cases...

Answer (score -1):

You can use `git log` to see how many commits of your master branch you want to undo. If, for example, you want to rollback 6 commits, just type:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~6
```

If you want to recover your merged status, you can use `reflog` to see the commit id of the last commit in the original master branch, and then check it out.

Comment: Unfortunately this will a) remove any non-merge commits on master within that range and b) break history if force-pushed to remote.